# Power BI Cummulative Subtraction

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a calculated table in which I get the percentage by dividing actual cost by total cost and then multiplying by 100.

I show this value on weekly basis like that:

```
Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4
-------+--------+--------+-------
    70 |     80 |     60 |     90
```

but I want to change it like this:

```
Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4
-------+--------+--------+-------
    70 |     80 |     60 |     90 
       |     10 |    -20 |     30
```

Currently I am using this formula:

```
Percentage_weekly_confirmation_rate = DIVIDE([Accepted PO Cost], [Total PO Cost])
```

`Accepted PO Cost` and `Total PO Cost` are both calculated values.

What should I do to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

I`ve loaded Week and Confirmation_Rate fields into PBI file with this simple SELECT:

```
SELECT 'Week_1' AS [Week], 70 AS Confirmation_Rate
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Week_2' AS [Week], 80 AS Confirmation_Rate
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Week_3' AS [Week], 60 AS Confirmation_Rate
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Week_4' AS [Week], 90 AS Confirmation_Rate
```

That`s how I can calculate what you need:

```
Column = 
VAR PreviousRow =
    TOPN (
        1;
        FILTER(Table_1; Table_1[Week] < EARLIER ( Table_1[Week] ) );
        [Week]; DESC
    )
VAR PreviousValue =
    MINX ( PreviousRow; DIVIDE(Table_1[Confirmation_Rate]; 1) )
RETURN
    DIVIDE(Table_1[Confirmation_Rate]; 1) - PreviousValue
```

Please try to replace my arguments in the DIVIDE() functions to yours and your Table_1[Week] field if named differently.

Comment: I needed dax formula i used this formula for cummulative sum but for subtraction after dividion i am not able to do this got stuck                                                    Accepted_COST_CUMMULATIVE = CALCULATE(
SUM(Report_Data[accepted_cost] ),
FILTER(ALL(Report_Data) ,
SUMX (FILTER(Report_Data, EARLIER( Report_Data[dev_tbi tbl_dim_date.week_of_month] ) <=  Report_Data[dev_tbi tbl_dim_date.week_of_month] ), Report_Data[accepted_cost] )
))

Comment: Having error in earlier functionCheck_   Value = 
VAR PreviousRow =
    TOPN (1,
        FILTER('Date Dim','Date Dim'[week_of_month] <= EARLIER('Date Dim'[week_of_month]) ),
        'Date Dim', DESC
    )
VAR PreviousValue =
    MINX ( PreviousRow, DIVIDE([Accepted PO Cost], [Total PO Cost]) )
RETURN
    DIVIDE([Accepted PO Cost], [Total PO Cost]) - PreviousValue

Comment: i simply now want to make the above formula to subtract values not to sum